# How to use array stored in another constant.js file in a component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a constant.js file which has all the static arrays for the application.
I need to use this file content in another component and map its value to a dropdown.

Comment: Welcome in Stackoverflow. We’d love to help you. To get a good Answer for your Question: 
Can you provide some code and/or more explanations of what you are doing, and what's wrong if there is. 
Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create helper file full of functions in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38402025/how-to-create-helper-file-full-of-functions-in-react-native)

Comment: Why not to simply `import` the `array constant` in your `component`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do like this:-

**constant.js**

```
const array = [
                  {
                      id:1, value:'option 1'
                  },
                  {
                      id:2, value:'option 2'
                  },
                  {
                      id:3, value:'option 3'
                  },
                  {
                      id:4, value:'option 5'
                  },
                  {
                      id:5, value:'option 5'
                  }
              ]

export default array
```

Now import this file to your component and use it

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Array from './constant'


export default class YourComponent extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <select>
                    {
                        Array.map((item, i) =>{
                            return(
                                <option key={i}>
                                {item.value}
                                </option>
                            )
                        }
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: But now again have a problem , if suppose  I have another dropdown also . The 2nd drop down should be populated on selection of any value in first dropdown . How can i achieve it? Please help anyone.

Comment: for that you can follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916852/react-js-populate-2nd-dropdown-based-on-selection-from-1st-dropdown